# Menubar using css and html

Tags: html, css, menubar

I have been trying to create a menubar. But the problem is that I am unable to get the submenu below the main menu items, instead they are displaying aligned with the main menu item.
Someone suggested using position:relative for the list items but it didn't help. 
Here's my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>

        *{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        body{

            padding:50px;
            font-family:verdana;

        }

        /*-------- Navigation menu-----------------*/
        /*========================================*/


        ul#mainitem , ul.sub1 , ul.sub2{
            list-style-type:none;
        }

        ul#mainitem li{
            outline: 1px solid red;
            width:115px;
            text-align:center;
            position: relative;
            float:left;
        }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="mainitem">

                <li><a href="#"> Item1 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item2 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item3 </a></li>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#"> Item3.1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Item3.2 </a></li>
                            <ul class="sub2">
                                <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.1 </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.2 </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.3 </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> Item3.3 </a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Item4 </a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

Could anyone help me out with this!
Thanks!

Comment: first, if you are going to make an entire website, don't put your style elements in the html file, create a seperate css file. Second, there are hundreds, maybe thousands of tutorials that can resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6eLbo9/)**

You need to change your HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="mainitem">
        <li> <a href="#"> Item1 </a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#"> Item1.1 </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item1.2 </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item2 </a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#"> Item2.1 </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item2.2 </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item3 </a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#"> Item3.1 </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item3.2 </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Item4 </a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#"> Item4.1 </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Item4.2 </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then this is the CSS for the menu:

```
ul#mainitem, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    position: absolute;
}
ul.sub1 li, ul.sub2 li {
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#mainitem > li {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width:115px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q1ycrfj9/

You want to have your submenu within the `li` tag of its parent and you want to use absolute positioning if the menu is going to appear and disappear. I've done the first steps for you below, but you'll need to do some cleaning and aligning.

HTML

```
 <body>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul id="mainitem">

            <li><a href="#"> Item1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item3 </a>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#"> Item3.1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Item3.2 </a></li>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.1 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.2 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Item3.2.3 </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Item3.3 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item4 </a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    body{

        padding:50px;
        font-family:verdana;

    }

    /*-------- Navigation menu-----------------*/
    /*========================================*/


    ul#mainitem , ul.sub1 , ul.sub2{
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    ul#mainitem li{
        outline: 1px solid red;
        width:115px;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
    }

.sub1{
    width: 115px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}


        </style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been through many tutorials but I haven't got the difference between position:relative and position:absolute.. Could you please help me understand this.

Comment: Think of absolute as taking its parent's original position and then ignoring everything like boundaries and padding and intersection. Absolute takes a position and will display its objects at that position no matter what is there. Heres a quick tutorial http://learnlayout.com/position.html